# There are twice as many coins on the balance as it should be, but when sending it becomes zero

Tags: transactions, balance

I sent myself coins from one wallet to another. After the coins came, I made a copy and deleted the wallet from my computer. After a while, I re-restored the wallet, the balance was three times larger, then he recalculated and the balance became twice as large. When trying to send a zero balance. I took out the private keys and inserted them into a new wallet, but nothing worked out. Please help me what's going on.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.stackexchange.com. In a comment you say you use Litecoin core. Unfortunately, for a few years now, this website only covers Bitcoin, not other cryptocurrencies.

Comment: Hi Sergey, it is difficult to follow your description of the problem. I gather that you had two wallets and sent from one wallet (Wallet A) into the other (Wallet B). Which wallet did delete, which wallet did you restore later? What were you trying to do when you sent a “zero balance”? Was the balance of that wallet zero, or were you trying to send 0 to the recipient?

Answer (score 0):

- What wallet are you using?
- You "made a copy", ok. Try out insert the mnemonic or private key itself and see what it gets.
- Check the transaction input/amount/outputs, not the wallet balance itself since you're having trouble. Do the math, no sats had been created out of thin air. It you sent to yourself, you should be able to open the wallets side by side and check it out.

> I took out the private keys and inserted them into a new wallet, but nothing worked out

Define ***nothing worked out***. It derived another address? The wallet didn't generate an address?

Comment: I deleted the wallet from which I sent it, there is no more access to it. I made a listtransaction and he showed that the coins came. I use litecoin core

Comment: When I copied the keys, I didn't even show the transactio